# C - How can I pass an array to a function, do some operations on it, and then return it to the main?

Tags: c, arrays

I am writing a program to encrypt some data and in order to do so I have an array that I need to pass to a function, and then it has to be returned to the main. I tried to do it but I get this message once it is executed: "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

This is how i tried to do it:

```
void shift3bit(int P[64])
{
   /*some operations*/
}

void main(void)
{
    int P[64];
    shift3bit;
}
```

Thanks a lot for the help, I am a newbie in programming.

Comment: `void shift3bit(int P[64])` is the same as `void shift3bit(int P*)`. You're passing a pointer, just modify it.

Comment: it did not fix the problem

Comment: What problem? You barely show us code and `shift3bit;` is nonsense anyway. How could that pass the compiler?

Comment: It should be `shift3bit(p);` not `shift3bit;`

Comment: @cad: Oh, it'll pass the compiler. You might get a warning if you asked for it, but it will compile just fine. The line just won't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Call the function concerned as:

```
shift3bit (P);
```

not

```
shift3bit;
```

Comment: Though correct, this does not explain anything. The OP identified themselves as a new programmer. Some explanation is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, first off, the set speech. If you've never programmed before,
you're studying the wrong language. C is low-level and you'll spend too
much time messing around with pointers and memory management, and
chasing obscure bugs. Python is a much better choice for your first
language. It will let you focus on the program and its logic, not
bit-fiddling.

As for the question, it's very simple. You're doing this:

```
shift3bit;
```

`shift3bit` is an identifier that references a function. When you do it
that way, semantically it's the same as if you'd done something like
this:

```
int x;
...
x;
```

It does nothing at all. What you want to do is **call** the function, by
including parentheses after the name:

```
shift3bit();
```

That would call the function. As it happens, you actually need to pass a
parameter as well:

```
shift3bit(P);
```

I'm guessing that being new to C, you simply forgot to include the
parentheses and the parameter. It's an easy mistake to make. I do it now
and then, and I've been programming for decades.

If any of this is the least bit unclear to you, go back and review that
part of the textbook. (Yes, even if you switch to studying Python as
recommended; calling functions this way is pretty universal among
declarative languages.)